# libming 0.4.2 installation giving error on OSX 10.7.4 x64 when building from source code

Tags: c, makefile, osx-lion, libming

I am trying to install libming 0.4.2 from source code on Intel Mac OSX 10.7.4 x64 (I already successfully installed it on Intel Mac OSX 10.6 i386) but it gives me following error when I try to  run ./configure (both with and without sudo)

```
config.status: creating util/Makefile
config.status: creating util/ming-config
config.status: creating ming.spec
config.status: creating src/ming_config.h
config.status: src/ming_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
sed: config/ltmain.sh: No such file or directory
sed: config/ltmain.sh: No such file or directory
mv: rename libtoolT to libtool: No such file or directory
cp: libtoolT: No such file or directory
chmod: libtool: No such file or directory
```

and of course after that make install fails. :(
(xcode and xcode command line tools are already installed)

Comment: It is not able to create those files may be. Check the file permissions.

Comment: I am running ./configure with sudo privileges.

Comment: Try `glibtoolize --force` before running the  `./configure` does that solve the problem?

Comment: nopes, following is the result:
$ sudo glibtoolize --force
glibtoolize: $pkgltdldir is not a directory: `/usr/bin/../share/libtool'

Comment: Its should've worked. But, if it still doesn't work, then post a  detailed report in the libming forums or register a bug in their website. They will be the best people for this problem.

Comment: @gmuhammad I've just solve the problem and want to share with you, I using  sudo vim /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize, searching for "pkgltdldir", and replaced "@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@"  with  "/usr/local/Cellar/" . Hope it can give you some hint. I just successfully build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following instructions/commands works for me on Mac OSX 10.7.4 x64.

```
 1. Install mac ports from http://www.macports.org/
 2. sudo port install automake
 3. sudo port install autoconf
 4. sudo port install libtool
 5. sudo port install intltoo 
 6. sudo port install pkgconfig
 7. sudo port install cmake
 8. glibtoolize --ltdl --force --copy
 9. autoreconf

 and then build your code using

 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

Comment: There's really no reason to run anything except `port` any maybe `make install` under sudo in the above. `glibtoolize`, `autoreconf`, `configure` and `make` should all be run as the normal user.

Comment: agreed. sudo removed from `glibtoolize`, `autoreconf`, `configure` and `make`

Answer (score 2):

These commands could work(step by step):

```
aclocal
glibtoolize --force
autoheader
autoconf
automake
./configure
make
make install
```

libming 0.4.2 might have problems like that because, it stopped at RC1.(esp. for Intel Mac Refer:http://www.libming.org/Mac_OS_X_Installation)

Try installing higher versions 0.4.3 and 0.4.4.

Comment: getting following error on aclocal:

$ sudo aclocal
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/bin/../share/automake-1.10 /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/bin/aclocal line 43.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/aclocal line 43.

Comment: The project I am working on is 0.4.2 specific, I am not sure future versions will be compatible or not.